# Is there better way to change string for evaluation

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, eval, calculator

Is there better way of changing one of numbers to float in division?
I am currently having 1 loop that scan my equation for '/' sign and second that take number after '/' and change it to float. How can I improve it?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

import Tkinter as tk


main = tk.Tk()
main.title('Calculator')


def insert_variable(i):
    """Inserts the user defined sign and puts it on the end the entry widget"""
    END = len(calc_entry.get())
    calc_entry.insert(END,i)

def calculate():
    ''' deletes all characters in the entry and inserts evaluation of the equation '''
    equation = calc_entry.get()
    try:
        calc_entry.delete(0, len(equation)) # deletes all characters in the entry
        for i in range(len(equation)-1):# loop for checking for special signs


            if equation[i] == '/': #if there is '/' sign change one of numbers to float
                for j in range(i+1,len(equation)): # loop for number of digits after '/' sign
                    if equation[j] == '.': # if there is dot go ones more
                        pass
                    else:
                        try:
                            int(equation[j])# if there is something other than digit go to exception
                        except ValueError:
                            equation = equation[:i+1] + str(float(equation[i+1:j])) + equation[j:]# change number after / to float and join all strings
                            break

            if equation[i] == '^': # if there is ^ sign change it for '**'
                equation = equation[:i] +'**'+ equation[i+1:]
                print equation


        calc_entry.insert(0, str(round(eval(equation), 3))) # evaluates (calculates) the equation after loop

    except SyntaxError:
        calc_entry.insert(0,'<ERROR>')
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        calc_entry.insert(0,'ERROR DIVISION BY 0')

calc_entry = tk.Entry(main) # creates an entry
calc_entry.grid(row =1, columnspan = 6)


bEquate = tk.Button(main, text="=", command = calculate)
bEquate.grid(row=5, column=3)

bDivision = tk.Button(main, text="/", command = lambda : insert_variable("/"))
bDivision.grid(row=3, column=5)

main.mainloop()
```

What if I have `sqrt()` function that gives sqrt sign to the last number? How can I implement it to the `calculate()` function?

```
sqrtChr = unichr(0x221A)
def insert_sqrt():
    """inserts sqrt sign"""
    global sqrtChr
    END = len(calc_entry.get())
    equation = calc_entry.get() # takes the whole user's equation from the entry
    for i in range(-1,-END-1,-1): # loop that goes from -1,-2,-3 to end-1
        if i == -END: # if there are no exceptions like '.' or special sign, inserts sqrt character at beginning of string in the entry
            calc_entry.insert(0,sqrtChr)
        elif equation[i] == '.': # if there is a dot in equation go to next character in equation
            pass
        else:
            try: # if there is a sign insert sqrt character after it and break loop
                int(equation[i])
            except ValueError:
                calc_entry.insert((END+i+1),sqrtChr)
                break
```

Comment: what do you try to do ? can't you use `split('/')` or even directly `eval("1/2")` (you can filter text to use only some chars and you couldn't have problem with insecure code).

Comment: BTW: `'2^3^4'.replace('^', '**')`

Comment: I made calculator which takes equation like "2+2/2+2" gives 5. With `split()` it won't work, Thanks for `replace` function.

Comment: BTW: `eval('2*PI*r', {'r': 2, 'PI': 3.1415})` gives `12.566` so you can use variables.

Comment: What if I have function `sqrt()` that gives  '√' sign at the beginning of last number like in: 9+9-√9, replace won't work because it will be `0.5**9` instead of `9**0.5`?

Comment: with `√` you will have to find not only `√` but also full number after this sign - you could try to create own function to parse it or you can try to use `regular expresion` with module `re` - and something better than `'√([0-9\.]+)'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
from __future__ import division
```

and `1/2` will gives you `0.5` - the same `eval("1/2")`